# How to run Angular serve, tests and lint in realtime simultaneously?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Currently, when developing a Angular applications in Visual Studio Code I have `ng serve` started.

It means the project is running in dev mode, and TypeScript compilation errors show up in the console. Also, some of errors are displayed in the debugging window.

Moreover since lint is configured, I see lint errors in currently opened files.

It helps develop the application without rebuilding it each time.

But if there is a linter error in a file that is not opened. I don't see it, until I call `ng lint` in the console.

The same goes for tests. In order to find errors I need to separately start `ng test`, or launch tests with a Visual Studio Code extension.

What I would like to achieve is to have realtime serving, linting and testing of my application. So that after each file change linter checks all files of the project for errors. And all tests are also executed at once.

How to run linting, testing and serving of whole Angular application in realtime based on file changes made with output being shown at once?

Comment: do you use linux?

Comment: @oded bd i use windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `ng serve` in one integrated terminal and then create a new integrated terminal by pressing the `+` icons.

[image]

You can run your test in the new terminal tab, and both `ng serve` and `ng test` will run concurrently.

If you want to run both `test` and `serve` from a single command then use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

install the package by

`npm install concurrently --save`

and modify `start script` in  `package.json` file as:

`"start": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"ng test\""`

now start the app by running `npm start`, this will run both rest script and serve.

`ng lint` will end as soon as listing for all files is finished, so better not to including it in the start script won't do much.

I Suggest installing `tslint` extension, which will show lint errors in real-time in the editor.

[image]

Lint errors are also visible in the `problems` tab of the integrated terminal window.

[image]